# Ho do i get the app config data/customer data, guest or logged in, in an app script?

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-app

I try to create an app script where i need to deny the finish process of an order under defined circumstances. Therefore i need access to the date of birth from a customer and a given variable in my app config. How can i get them?

The line-items for example i get like this:

```
{# @var services \Shopware\Core\Framework\Script\ServiceStubs #}
{% set items = services.cart.items %}
```

Comment: Does it even make sense to try to stop the order process there or would you rather stop someone from putting items into the basket in the first place?
which option guarantees the best customer experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the customer from the `SalesChannelContext`, given they're logged in.

```
{% if hook.salesChannelContext.customer %}
    {% set birthday = hook.salesChannelContext.customer.birthday %}
{% endif %}
```

Regarding your comment, the cart manipulation hook is probably what you want to use. For instance you could use the script to [add errors and notifications to the cart](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/apps/app-scripts/cart-manipulation#add-errors-and-notifications-to-the-cart) given a condition based on the birthday.

Comment: THANK A LOT!
it was so easy and i could not find it. 

now i am still struggling with the app configuration itself in there. should i ask another question here on stackoverflow for it?